# Query params lost after redirect with absolute path

Tags: angular

I configured the routes for my angular application in the routes arrray:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'a', redirectTo: '/c', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
    {path: 'b', redirectTo: 'c', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
    {path: 'c', component: TestComponent}]
```

If I navigate to /a?param='test' I cannot see the QueryParams anymore in my TestComponent. If I navigate to /b it works.

Is there a way to keep the query params even when redirecting with an absolute path?

This is just an example - my real app is far more complex and I need to navigate from one childcomponent to another branch of my routing tree - and therefore have to use absolute paths.

Comment: If the absolute paths are inside your application I believe you can pass all the parameters and query parameters that you need using `routerLink` and `queryParamsHandling` and `router.navigate` in the `component.ts` file.

If those absolute paths are outside your application I think you will need to specify them each time.